Move icon to dock with GNOME
With 22.04 with GNOME Version 42.9,I am not able to drag icon into dock.  I cannot find any information about this issue.  The icon points to (invokes a 3rd party application) "thinkorswim".
/home/george/Desktop/thinkorswim.desktop file contains:
Type=Application
Name=thinkorswim
Exec="/home/george/thinkorswim"  %U
Icon=/home/george/thinkorswim/.intstall4j/thinkorswim.png
StartupWMClass=install4j-com-devexperts-jnlp-Launcher

You cannot drag icons into the dock. The dock is automatically populated with icons of running programs. If you want an icon to also be available if the program is not running, then you "Add to favorites" in the right-click menu.
If you want to be able to turn the icon of your custom application into a favorite, i.e., permanent icon, then install its desktop file in a dedicated folder, where the Dock searches for such launchers. One of these directories is ~/.local/share/applications.

Move your /home/george/Desktop/thinkorswim.desktop file to a directory /home/george/.local/share/applications. Create that directory if you do not have it already.
Wait a few seconds. The icon now will be picked up by the menu system, where you should be able to find it.
If you run the application now from the menu, you will be able to turn its icon into a favorite by right-clicking on the icon and selecting "Add to favorites".

